# Approximate increase in circumference of circle giving increase in area of 3%

Tags: calculus

Find the percentage increase in the circumference of a circle, which will result in an increase in the area of the circle of approximately 3%.

I have assumed the percentage change in circumference is the same as the percentage change in r, since circumference is $2\pi r$.

I have said $A = \pi r^2, \frac{dA}{dr} = 2\pi r$

$\frac{\delta A}{\delta r} \approx \frac{dA}{dr}$

where $\delta$ refers to "a small increase".

$\delta A = \frac{dA}{dr}.dr$

$\frac{3A}{100} \approx 2\pi r.\delta r$

But I cannot get this to equal the answer in the book, which is 1.5%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the OP's notation, in particular $\delta A/\delta r\approx dA/dr=2\pi r$, we have
$${\delta A\over A}={2\pi r\delta r\over\pi r^2}=2{\delta r\over r}$$

so if $\delta A/A\approx3\%$, then $\delta r/r\approx1.5\%$. (And since $C=2\pi r$, we have $\delta C=2\pi\delta r$, hence $\delta C/C=\delta r/r=1.5\%$ as well, as the OP observed.)

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\pi r^2 \implies dA=2\pi r dr \implies  \frac{dA}{A}\%=2\frac{dr}{r}\% \implies \frac{dr}{r}\%=3/2$$

Npw $$P=2\pi r \implies \frac{dP}{P}\%=\frac{dr}{r}\% \implies \frac{dP}{P}\%=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

As we have relative variations, we can drop any constant factor. Then we take $r=1$ and compare

$$\frac{(1+\delta)-1}{1}=\delta$$ to $$\frac{(1+\delta)^2-1}{1}=2\delta+\delta^2\approx 2\delta.$$